# Why can mitochondria make only 34 molecules (rather than 61 molecules) of ATP ？

Tags: biochemistry, cellular-respiration

Why can mitochondria make only 34 molecules (not 61 molecules) of ATP from the energy obtained from the oxidation in the electron transfer system of NADH and FADH<sub>2</sub> generated by oxidation of glucose in glycolysis and the tricarboxylic acid cycle?

The electron transfer system oxidizes 10 mol of NADH and 2 mol of FADH<sub>2</sub> obtained from glycolyses and the tricarboxylic acid cycle, and up to 34 mol of ATP can be obtained by the electron transfer system alone. Complexes I and II take energy from NADH and FADH<sub>2</sub>, and complexes I, III, and IV are also proton pumps that pump hydrogen ions against a concentration gradient. The reactions carried out by the four enzymes, known as complexes I–IV, and their Gibbs free energies are as follows;

- Complex I: (NADH + H<sup>+</sup> + CoQ → NAD<sup>+</sup> + CoQH<sub>2</sub> — ΔG˚′(1) = -71 kJ/mol)×10
- Complex Ⅱ： (FADH<sub>2</sub> + succinic acid + CoQ → FAD + CoQH<sub>2</sub> + Fumaric acid — ΔG˚′(2) =-2.9 kJ/mol)×2
- Complex Ⅲ：(CoQH<sub>2</sub> + 2 cyt c(Fe<sup>3+</sup>) → CoQ + 2
  cyt c(Fe2+) + 2H<sup>+</sup> — ΔG˚′(3) =   -41 kJ/moll)×12
- Complex Ⅳ：(4 cyt
  c(Fe<sup>2+</sup>) + O<sub>2</sub> + 4H<sup>+</sup> → 4 cyt c(Fe<sup>3+</sup>) + 2H<sub>2</sub>O — ΔG˚′(4) =  -110 kJ/mol)×6

Therefore, the ‘net’ reaction, from complex I–IV, is as follows:
10 NADH + 2 FADH<sub>2</sub> + 6 O<sub>2</sub>+ 2 Succinic acid → 12 H<sub>2</sub>O + 10 NAD + 2 FAD + 2 Fumaric acid — ΔG˚′ (total)

Here,
ΔGo' (total)= 10ΔGo'(1) +  2Go'(2) + 12ΔGo'(3) +  6ΔGo'(4) 
= 10*(-71) +  2*(-2.9) + 12*(-41) +  6*(-110) kJ/mol
= -1867.8  kJ/mol

The following reactions then occurs in complex V using the above ΔG˚′ (total);
ADP + Pi → ATP , ΔGo'(5)=  -30.5 kJ/mol

Simply considering abovementioned only,  the amount of ATP that can be generated from the energy derived from a single molecule of glucose entering the electron transfer system via NADH or FADH2 is as follows;
-1867.8/-30.5 =61.2 ATPs

So, my question is as folilows;

> Why can mitochondria make only 34 molecules (not 61 molecules) of ATP from the energy obtained from a single molecule of glucose in the electron transfer system?

**I would like to ask this question especially from the perspective of Gibbs energy balance (in terms of energy loss).**

Related

- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/72457/why-delta-g-nfe-and-not-f-integraldne/176835#176835
  [How many molecules of ATP are actually produced in aerobic respiration?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/89245/how-many-molecules-of-atp-are-actually-produced-in-aerobic-respiration)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental *flaw in the poster’s logic* is the implicit supposition that if a mitochondrial (or other) oxidation reaction has a standard Gibbs Free Energy change of -*x* kJ/mol, all of that can be used to drive the reaction ADP + Pi → ATP; and that one can just divide *x* by 30.5 to find how much ATP is produced.

**One cannot.**

One needs to consider the actual physico-chemical reactions of the oxidations and the subsequent phosphorylations of ADP. When you do this you will find that *much of the free energy of the oxidation reactions is not used to drive a chemical reaction, but is converted into (‘lost’, in the terms of the poster) heat energy.*

Even if one considers the simplest situation, ‘substrate level’ phosphorylations — reactions in which the oxidation of NAD<sup>+</sup> is *coupled directly* to the synthesis of ATP or GTP — there is no logical reason why the free energy change should be zero. The oxidation reaction may well have a –ΔG˚′ of greater absolute magnitude than the +ΔG˚′ required to synthesize NTP, and the difference will be released as heat. This is indeed the case for the succinyl-CoA synthetase reaction which generates GTP in the tricarboxylic acid cycle.

However the *mitochondrial oxidation reactions are **not** coupled directly to generation of ATP*. They are used to pump protons across a membrane, and to generate a membrane potential, which is the basis of the proton-motive force used to drive ATP synthetase and synthesize ATP. There is no reason to expect that all the free energy from the oxidation reactions will be conserved as a proton gradient and membrane potential, and good reason to suppose that it will not.